# Finding out class from predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using predict_proba from scikit-learn to find the probability of a document being assigned to a particular topic. Instead of printing out just the top 1 topic and assigning input document X to that topic Y, I am instead interested in printing out the top 5 probabilities to verify if the classification is consistent. However, how can I find out which topics do these top 5 probabilities belong to among 88 topics.

Here is the code and output:

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(matrix_tmp, label_tmp)

y_train_pred = model1.predict_log_proba(matrix_tmp_test)
order=np.argsort(y_train_pred, axis=1)
print(order[:, -5:])
```

So this prints out a matrix as follows:

```
[[38 11  6 66  0]
 [20 13 11  0  1]
 [61 11  0 13  1]
 ..., 
 [19 30 13  0  1]
 [13 34 75  0  1]
 [ 0 46  3  1 40]]
```

As per the sorting, 0 represents the topic with highest probability and 66 second highest and so on. My question is how do I find out which topics are these numbers in the matrix referring to. There are a total of 88 topics(labeled from 0 to 87 as per *model.classes_*, out of which only the top 5 are being considered. So how can I print the topics in the similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. I think the following simple solution should work (I quickly tested it and it worked for me at least):

```
print(model.classes_[order[:, -5:]])
```